# My elements are overlapping with one another

Tags: html, css

My html elements are overlapping with one another and I'd like to know why.

From what I understand, and what the developer tools are telling me, is that the origin input box `class="tripOrigin"`  is being blocked by the Start Date `class="tripStartDate"`, and it's making the blinking cursor not appear.  Other element's are doing this too, the adult selection drop down button is being block by the flight class, and I can't select the number of adult's in the search engine.

[image: Error image]

### **CSS & HTML**

```css
.flightPill {
  width: 100px;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: goldenrod;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  color: white;
  border-radius: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.hotelPill {
  width: 100px;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: goldenrod;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  color: white;
  border-radius: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.carPill {
  width: 100px;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: goldenrod;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  color: white;
  border-radius: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.travelSearchBar {
  width: 1000px;
  height: 400px;
  background-color: black;
  opacity: 0.9;
}

.tripOrigin {
  color: white;
  position: relative;
  right: 300px;
}

.tripDestination {
  color: white;
  position: relative;
  right: 300px;
}

.tripStartDate {
  position: relative;
  bottom: 150px;
}

.tripEndDate {
  position: relative;
  bottom: 150px;
}

.adultSelect {
  position: relative;
  left: 200px;
  bottom: 250px;
}

.childSelect {
  position: relative;
  left: 200px;
  bottom: 250px;
}

.classSelect {
  position: relative;
  left: 300px;
  bottom: 330px;
}

.innerbackgroundSearchbar {
  width: 80%;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: gray;
  position: relative;
  top: 25%;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <center>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <div class="travelSearchBar">
      <div class="moveTravelPills">

        <div class="flightPill">
          <p><b>Flights</b></p>
        </div>

        <!-- <div class="hotelPill">
                    <p><b>Hotels</b></p>
                </div>
                <div class="carPill">
                    <p><b>Cars</b></p>
                </div> -->
      </div>
      <div class="innerbackgroundSearchbar">

        <div class="tripOrigin">
          <br>
          <label><b>Origin:</b></label>
          <br>
          <br>
          <input id="origin" />
        </div>
        <br>
        <div class="tripDestination">
          <label><b>Destination:</b></label>
          <br>
          <br>
          <input/>
        </div>

        <div class="tripStartDate">
          <br>
          <label><b>Start Date:</b></label>
          <br>
          <br>
          <input/>
        </div>
        <br>
        <div class="tripEndDate">
          <label><b>End Date:</b></label>
          <br>
          <br>
          <input/>
        </div>
        <div class="adultSelect">
          <label><b>Adult:</b></label>
          <br>
          <select id="adult">
            <option>1</option>
            <option>2</option>
            <option>3</option>
            <option>4</option>
          </select>
        </div>
        <br>

        <div class="childSelect">
          <label><b>Child:</b></label>
          <br>
          <select id="child">
            <option>0</option>
            <option>1</option>
            <option>2</option>
            <option>3</option>
            <option>4</option>
          </select>
        </div>
        <div class="classSelect">
          <label><b>Class:</b></label>
          <br>
          <select id="class">
            <option>Economy</option>
            <option>Premium</option>
            <option>Business</option>
          </select>
        </div>

        <br>
        <button>Search</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </center>
</div>
```

Comment: Side note, don't use `<br>` for spacing and don't use `<center>` at all

Comment: you could use `z-index` property to move some elements to the back of other elements [Sets the front-to-back ordering of elements](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorials/HTML_CSS/CSS/CSS_Box%20Model%20and%20Layout/Sets_the_front_to_back_ordering_of_elements.htm#:~:text=The%20z%2Dindex%20property%20sets,useful%20only%20when%20elements%20overlap.)

Comment: Thanks @ChrisG, but the start date element. Is blocking the Origin and it look's like the origin is blocking the start date, if I use z-index

Comment: mm why are they on separate divs tho?  when they are right next to each other?

Comment: easier to move, with `position: relative; right:300px;` then learning flex box or css grid

Comment: `<div>` is a block element, so it is naturally taking the whole width.

Comment: @FarhanIbnWahid, thanks for that information. I've started replacing the `<div>` tags with `<span>` tags.

Comment: You are shooting yourself in the foot here with positioning everything manually like this.   You will have far less problems by using Flexbox or even the standard box model.  It will also be a lot less code

Comment: I think it would cost only 10% of your time if you would have used Flexbox to build it perfectly compared to what you have spent for this. It is not that hard to learn and apply for a simple layout like this. But if you really don't want to use it then at least use `display: inline` and `display: inline-block` for those inside divs and then position them. Don't use `position: relative` for this kind of things because then you can not make it responsive for all the different screen resolutions.

Comment: As others have said, it might take more time *today* to learn flexbox, but it should really only take a day to pick it up and it is something you will literally use multiple times in every project. It takes FAR less code and is FAR easier to work with than what you're doing, and it's responsive so it takes much less work to format across mobile and desktop.

Here's [an article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Flexbox) that walks you through how it works, and here's [a game](https://flexboxfroggy.com/) to help you get the hang of it.